# cx_Freeze делает не рабочие exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze, openpyxl

Проблема с cx_Freeze при компиляции в exe.
Если в коде есть импорт какой либо библиотеки, например openpyxl (я работаю с чтением и записью документов Office) то exeшник открывает окно которое я нарисовал, но падает после попытки открытия файла excel (эта функция висит на отдельной кнопке в окне GUI и запускает кусок кода с openpyxl).

Работаю в PyCharm, он как я понимаю автоматом создаёт venv под мой проект. Все сторонние библиотеки я устанавливаю через него же, в File - Settings - Project: Excel - Project Interpreter.
В ПиЧарме код работает отлично.

Если в исходниках вместо импорта openpyxl поставить заглушку то скомпилированный бинарник работает.

После компиляции создается НЕ пустая папка build_windows\lib\openpyxl т.е. сама библиотека вроде копируется.

В чем может быть проблема, куда копать?

код файла setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable('superMain.py',
                          targetName='Calculator.exe',
                          base='Win32GUI',
                          icon='it.ico')]
excludes = ['logging', 'unittest', 'email', 'html', 'http', 'urllib', 'xml',
            'unicodedata', 'bz2', 'select']
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_msvcr': True,
        'excludes': excludes,        
        'build_exe': 'build_windows',
    }
}
setup(name='Калькулятор конструкций',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='Учебная программа',
      executables=executables,
      options=options)
```

Код который запускается по кнопке и вызывает падение:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from open_patch_file import wb_patch # переменная содержит путь до книги

name_column = 3 #Столбец с наименованием сортамента
qant_column = 4 #Столбец с колличеством
length_column = 5 #Столбец с длиной
start_row = 2 #Строка с которой начинаются данные

wb = load_workbook(wb_patch)
sheet = wb.active

xer = 1 # Поиск разрывов в таблице из пустых строк
while sheet.cell(row=xer, column=name_column).value is not None \
        or sheet.cell(row=xer, column=qant_column).value is not None\
        or sheet.cell(row=xer, column=length_column).value is not None:
    xer = xer + 1

sortament = {}
for i in range(start_row, xer):
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=name_column).value == None:  # Проверка на пустые строки
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=name_column).value = 'Пустая строка'
    sort = sheet.cell(row=i, column=name_column).value.replace("\n",
                                                               "").strip()  # Удаляем \n оставшихся от экселя и обрезаем через strip лишние пробелы по концам
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=length_column).value == None or type(
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=length_column).value) == str:  # Проверка на пустые строки или лажу в графе "длина"
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=length_column).value = 0
    length = sheet.cell(row=i, column=qant_column).value * sheet.cell(row=i, column=length_column).value / 1000
    sortament[i - 2] = tuple((sort, round(length, 3)))
rezult_calc = {}

for y in sortament:
    sort_name = sortament[y][0]
    if sort_name in rezult_calc:
        rezult_calc[sort_name] += sortament[y][1]
    else:
        rezult_calc[sort_name] = sortament[y][1]
```

Comment: русских букв случайно в путях нет?

Comment: русских названий нет точно, я слежу за этим

Comment: И главное падает без всяких объявлений

Comment: тогда как вы собираете exe? добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста, скрипт настроек сборки и команду запуска

Comment: попробуйте добавить `build_exe_options` по примеру, только с вашим модулем: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script. Там есть опции `packages` и `includes`. Возможно нужно вручную их прописать. Еще я бы порекомендовал попробовать запустить ваш скрипт отдельно из командной строки без участия PyCharm.

Comment: @Bogdan Спасибо большое! ваш совет с ссылкой на эталонный setup сработал! проблема была в моём setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой setup.py на эталонный образец из https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script